# How to bind a UWP project image from another project?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have [image control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc7dZ.png) in UWP page. I wrote path to sourse that is located in other project, but image don't show nor designer nor runtime. How to fix this problem?

```
<Page
x:Class="Platform.Universal.LoadingWindow.LoadingWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="Transparent">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="LoadingImage"
        Stretch="Fill" 
           Source="ms-appdata:///Resources.Universal/Resources/ChangableFiles/Default/LoadingImage.png" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The only way you could possibly do it if you had set the `broadFileSystemAccess` in the manifest, then loaded the image from the file system path in the code behind and assigned it (or something similar from the view model).

But just to note that on Microsoft Store it is almost certain that your app will be denied to use `broadFileSystemAccess` if this is the reason to ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ms-appx:` instead of `ms-appdata:` and make sure you have access to directory where the image is stored.

You can use `Assets` directory to store the images and easily use it in the code.

For e.g: `Source="ms-appx:///Assets/LoadingImage.png" />`